# Git and Capistrano : Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, netbeans, capistrano

On my server I have changed my repository "**/var/www/depotsGit/dome.git**" to "**/home/dome/www/depotsGit/dome.git**" with "mv" shell command.

In my computer, with Netbeans, I have changed my Git configuration for the new repository. **Commit and Push work well**. :)

I have changed Capistrano config for new repository. But now, when I want to deploy my project With capistrano, I have this error :

```
dome@dome50:/var/www/symfony/dome$ **cap production deploy
00:00 git:wrapper
  01 mkdir -p /tmp/dome.fr/
✔ 01 dome@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX 0.445s
  Uploading /tmp/dome.fr/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
  02 chmod +rx /tmp/dome.fr/git-ssh.sh
✔ 02 dome@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX 0.066s
00:00 git:check
  01 git ls-remote --heads ssh://git@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9322/home/dome/www/depotsGit/dome.git/
  01 03e988a49e7eda6563a520c3a37fb751c72fb718   refs/heads/master
✔ 01 dome@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX 0.241s
00:00 deploy:check:directories
  01 mkdir -p /home/dome/www/dev/dome/shared /home/dome/www/dev/dome/releases
✔ 01 dome@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX 0.071s
00:01 deploy:check:linked_dirs
  01 mkdir -p /home/dome/www/dev/dome/shared/app/logs
✔ 01 dome@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX 0.062s
00:01 git:clone
  The repository mirror is at /home/dome/www/dev/dome/repo
00:01 git:update
  01 git remote update --prune
  01 Récupération de origin
  01 fatal: '/var/www/depotsGit/dome.git/' does not appear to be a git repository
  01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  01
  01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  01 and the repository exists.
  01 error: Impossible de récupérer origin
```

I had forgotten to change something on the server but do not know what ... :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a cache trouble with git.

Remove the folder shared/cached-copy to force git to fetch new content.

If you use capistrano 3 +
I suggest to simply delete your-app-name/repo (not sure, but If I were you I will rename this folder temporary to something else, and try a new deploy)